# Least equatorial ( and tidal) bulge consistent with modest amounts of water in polar regions

Tags: geology, geophysics, plate-tectonics, models, geodynamics

In World Building I asked a question about the climate of an hypothetical planet.

[There](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/159199/climate-in-an-hypothetical-planet#comment499721_159199) [Vogon poet](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/69877/vogon-poet) said that

> Everyone above 10° latitude will be in permanent drought

Considering that there were no Milankovitch cycles (with a year of exactly 31104000 seconds (360 Earth days) and a day of exactly 86400 seconds (24 hours) and a circular orbit with a distance between the surface of Earth and the Sun's surface equal to the harmonic mean of the current distance), Earth was an oblate spheroid (with the same mass) with a perfectly smooth surface (only allowing for moderate variance due to fauna, flora and civilisation), there were only 2 bodies in the universe Earth and a Sun (a perfect ball with smooth surface and uniform density with the same amount of radiation).

**What would be the least equatorial bulge consistent with modest amounts of water in polar regions?**

Comment: Thank you earnestly for the help Fred.

Comment: Do you think I should define polar regions like say above (and below) 80° or 85° Latitude (North and South)